# How do I allow users to select text from a Text widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

On Android, I'm used to [TextView's textIsSelectable attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_textIsSelectable) but I didn't see that in the Text docs.

Currently I'm using a TextField (editable) and not saving any changes to the displayed text. My primary need is to allow copy-paste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this in one of my projects with the following (simplified) code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();
  String _text = 'TestString';

  /// Pastes given String to the clipboard and shows Popup-Snackbar
  void copyToClipboard(String toClipboard) {
    ClipboardData data = new ClipboardData(text: toClipboard);
    Clipboard.setData(data);
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
      content: new Text(toClipboard + ' copied to clipboard.'),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('TestProject'),
      ),
      body: new InkWell(
        onLongPress: () => copyToClipboard(_text),
        child: new Center(
            child: new Text(_text),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So just wrap your text in a widget that can detect gestures or use a [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to call the clipboard method.
Hope it helps.